# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userRole')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to reference a field in Firebase Firestore called userRole in the collection `companies/{currentCompany/users/{currentUserUID}`.

Using the company code in the users collection (this all works when I `console.log`).

However I am getting an undefined error in the second `useEffect`.

Even if I add the hardcopied data/code/values in the request, I still get the same error.

```
const [currentUserUID, setCurrentUserUID] = useState(null)
const [currentUserCompanyCode, setCurrentUserCompanyCode] = useState(null)
const [currentUserCompanyRole, setCurrentUserCompanyCodeRole] = useState(null)
    
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUserUID != null) {
    const docRefUser = doc(projectDb, "users", currentUserUID);
    getDoc (docRefUser).then((doc) => {
      setCurrentUserCompanyCode(doc.data().companyCode)
    })
  }
}, [currentUserUID]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUserCompanyCode != null && currentUserUID != null) {
    const docRefCompany = doc(projectDb, "companies", currentUserCompanyCode, "users", currentUserUID);
    getDoc (docRefCompany).then((doc) => {
      setCurrentUserCompanyCodeRole(doc.data().userRole)
    })
  }
}, [currentUserCompanyCode, currentUserUID]);

console.log(currentUserCompanyCode)
console.log(currentUserCompanyRole)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated the fields/document/collection in Firebase Firestore and that fixed the issue.